# Procedure or function 'insertcustrec5' expects parameter '@tb1', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, .net

When i click the Save Button in my page, it executes this

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and then it calls `save()` function.
In `save()` function it calls stored procedure insertcustrec5. As soon as it reaches to the stored procedure insertcustrec5, it raises error

> "Procedure or function 'insertcustrec5' expects parameter '@tb1',
>   which was not supplied"

but i supplied..n i checked every parameter getting its value still this error keeps on occurring.

--> My Stored Procedure is:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertcustrec5]
 (
   @RID int,
   @Remarks varchar(MAX),
   @CRDate date,
   @ChallanNo float,
   @Quantity float,
   @tb1 int,
   @Amount float
 )
 As
 INSERT INTO Customer_Receive(ChallanNo, CRDate, RID, Quantity, Remarks,CustID,Amount)
 VALUES     (@ChallanNo,@CRDate,@RID,@Quantity,@Remarks,@tb1,@Amount)
```

--> Save Function which calls Stored procedure is:

```
public void save()
    {

        data.AddParameter("RID", this.rid);
        data.AddParameter("CustID", this.tb1);
        data.AddParameter("Remarks", this.remarks);
        data.AddParameter("CRDate", this.CRDate);
        data.AddParameter("ChallanNo", this.ChallanNo);
        data.AddParameter("Quantity", this.quantity);
        data.ExecuteNonQuery("insertcustrec5");
```

--> ExecuteNonQuerry Function:-

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            this.OpenConnection();
            command.Connection = this.connection;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(cmdParams.ToArray());
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

--> Save Button Click:-

```
 protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bllCustomer_Receive receive = new bllCustomer_Receive();
        string datetime = txtcrdate.Text;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "d/M/yyyy", null);
        receive.CRDate = dt;
        receive.ChallanNo = txtchallan.Text;
        receive.rid = txtrid.Text;
        receive.quantity = float.Parse(txtquantity.Text);
        receive.remarks = txtremarks.Text;
        tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(drpdwncustID.SelectedItem);
        receive.tb1 = tb1.Text;
        receive.save();
    }
```

Comment: You didn't supply it. Did you even read the code you posted?

Comment: Note: when you fix this for `tb1` you'll get a similar problem for `Amount`...

Comment: *but i supplied..n i checked every parameter getting its value still this error keeps on occuring.* This is not true. You are not supplying the parameter or you're not showing us the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write while adding parameters to sp

```
data.AddParameter("tb1", this.tb1);
```

instead of

```
 data.AddParameter("CustID", this.tb1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you are not providing the `@tb1` parameter (just as the error says) in the following part of your code:

```
    data.AddParameter("RID", this.rid);
    data.AddParameter("CustID", this.tb1);
    data.AddParameter("Remarks", this.remarks);
    data.AddParameter("CRDate", this.CRDate);
    data.AddParameter("ChallanNo", this.ChallanNo);
    data.AddParameter("Quantity", this.quantity);
    data.ExecuteNonQuery("insertcustrec5");
```

And while you're at it, you should add a line to add the `@amount` parameter, too...